# Override font weight applied by jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make the font weight normal instead of bold which jquery mobile makes by default.

```
<div id="cont" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose shipping method:</label>
    <select style="font-weight: normal" name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I tried both with inline style and javaScript

```
$('#select-choice-1').css("font-weight", "normal");
```

But none worked , it still showing bold. Please suggest how to make it unbold.

http://jsfiddle.net/neilghosh/MECXW/6/

Comment: your fiddle link gives 404 error please correct it

Comment: Thanks , I corrected the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you inspect the rendered page with firebug or similar, you would see that at runtime html structure is quite different from source html, courtesy of jQuery-ui that generates the pretty box:

```
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="ui-btn-text">Standard: 7 day</span>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow"></span>
</span>
```

You want to add a css rule to override it:

```
#cont .ui-btn-text{font-weight:normal;}​
```

The id reference is so that it only applies to this particular place; remove it if you want to apply normal font weight everywhere. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MECXW/9/