# Changing ui-link font-weight to normal

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to display links generated as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">http://www.stackoverflow.com/</a>
```

with a normal font-weight instead of the default bold that comes from JQM. I tryed with something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9715387/386738) and changed the ui-link element in my css like this:

```
.ui-link {font-weight: normal;}
```

but it wont work, see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MECXW/131/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Web Inspector/Debugger of your browser to check which rule is setting the `font-weight` and make sure your rule is of the same or higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

For example, in your fiddle the rule setting the `font-weight` has the selector `.ui-body-c .ui-link`, so if you use the same selector in your stylesheet (and include it after the jQuery style sheet) you won't have a problem:

```
.ui-body-c .ui-link {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.ui-link {font-weight: normal !important;}`

Comment: It works on the fiddle, but it does not work on my android web-app for some reason.

Comment: It seems to work on device if I add the style directly on the "a" element instead of writing it in the css...